Need help with understanding "Sort Apex Batch Action Results by Request Order" release update
I'm reviewing the release updates for my org. I came across this particular update and I couldn't find more information about this in the internet. What they are mean "Apex batch action results"? Can somebody help me with understanding this and if you have any sample code for this apex batch action results, please put it in the notes.

Looks like they posted the release update here https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_release_update_sort_apex_batch_action_results_by_request_order.htm&release=250&type=5
